# How to get note names below staff in Lilypond?

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond

I am a beginner at creating scores with Lilypond and I wonder if is there any way to make Lilypond automatically put note names below the staff (or above)?  I searched the documentation but could not find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [`NoteNames` context](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/internals/notenames) which seems to do what you want. I haven't tested the solution below, but I'm glad you did and it worked for you:

```
scale = \relative c' { c d e f g a b c }

\new Staff {
  <<
    \scale
    \context NoteNames {
      \set printOctaveNames = ##f
      \scale
    }
  >>
}
```